# Android SwipeToRefresh - Confilct with RecyclerView when swiping down

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, swiperefreshlayout

So I have a fragment with 2 RecyclerView lists. I want to swipe fragment to refresh those lists but when I scroll one of those lists to see hidden elements SwipeToRefresh refreshes those lists. How to prevent it from that?

Here is my XML layout:

```
<FrameLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/main_fragment">

    <android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
        android:id="@+id/main_fragment_swipe_to_refresh"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
            android:id="@+id/main_fragment_coordinator_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:weightSum="2">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:layout_weight="1">

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_margin="4dp"
                        android:textSize="18sp"
                        android:textColor="@color/primary_dark"
                        android:text="Najpopularniejsze przepisy" />

                    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                        android:id="@+id/top_recipes_recycler_view"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:scrollbars="vertical" />

                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:layout_weight="1">

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_margin="4dp"
                        android:textSize="18sp"
                        android:textColor="@color/primary_dark"
                        android:text="Najnowsze przepisy" />

                    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                        android:id="@+id/latest_recipes_recycler_view"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:scrollbars="vertical" />

                </LinearLayout>

            </LinearLayout>

        </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

    </android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>

</FrameLayout>
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You can consume the swipe down event in RecycleView when it can scroll up.

Just custom the RecycleView and intercept the event when you need.

Comment: Can you tell sth more? I'm just starting with those things :) Thnks

Comment: some kind like the below link will do.